# AWS IoT Core: Multiple DynamoDB inserts for one MQTT message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I'm using AWS IoT Core with a DynamoDB rule for an MQTT topic. My JSON payload looks something like this:

```
{
  "car_id": 52,
  "timestamp": "2020-08-31 12:50:00",
  "passengers": [
    {
      "passenger_id": 143,
      "passenger_name": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "passenger_id": 144,
      "passenger_name": "Bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the IoT rule to insert multiple rows in a DynamoDB table from this payload, which would look like so:

```
car_id    timestamp              passenger_id    passenger_name
52        2020-08-31 12:50:00    143             Foo
52        2020-08-31 12:50:00    144             Bar
```

i.e. essentially doing a JOIN between the outer data (`car_id`, `timestamp`) and the inner rows (`passengers`), and inserting one row into the DB for each `passenger`.

Any suggestions on how to do this with the IoT Rule SQL? Is it possible?

Note: I've considered breaking this into multiple MQTT messages (one for each `passenger`), but that runs the risk of some messages succeeding and being inserted and some not. I don't want any records inserted unless all records for a `car` can be inserted.

EDIT: Related but separate question: is it possible to use templated fields for things like the `${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}` field that you can use for policies?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can insert 2 rows using one Rule Action (maybe you can) but it may also be easier to use a Lambda to accomplish your goal.  Have you considered that option?

Comment: I have, but based on preliminary calculations, adding a Lambda in there would increase the overall cost by at least 20%.

Comment: That suggests that you must have quite a lot of data coming in.  Lambda is cheap!  If it's just doing the inserts you could probably get it all done within 100ms and 128 MB RAM.  Even if the cost goes up, perhaps it's better than doing something unconventional or less explicit since this doesn't appear to be a regular use case for the IoT Core Rule Action.